# When to use parentheses around propositional variables?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The following two questions from a text book are written fairly similarly, but one answer uses parenthesis while the other answer does not. I used parentheses for both of my own answers, as that is how I interpreted them myself.

What are some of the written or unwritten indicators that can be used to tell whether parentheses are required for a proposition?

Let p, q, and r be the propositions
*p* : Grizzly bears have been seen in the area.
*q* : Hiking is safe on the trail.
*r* : Berries are ripe along the trail.

Question A: `Grizzly bears have not been seen in the area and hiking on the trail is safe, but berries are ripe along the trail.`

Answer A (mine): $(\lnot p \land q) \land r$

Answer A (textbook solution): $\lnot p \land q \land r$

Question B: `If berries are ripe along the trail, hiking is safe if and only if grizzly bears have not been seen in the area.`

Answer B (mine): $r \rightarrow (q \iff \lnot p)$

Answer B (textbook solution): $r \rightarrow (q \iff \lnot p)$

Comment: Are you familiar with the [associative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)? If an operation is associative, as is the case with $\land$ in your first example, parenthesis are redundant. If the operation is not associative, parenthesis are generally required to prevent ambiguity.

Comment: To the second question, your answer matches that in the textbook.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood yes it does. I was demonstrating that interpretations can match for one question, but not match for the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in both your solutions.

In your first answer, the parentheses are perfectly appropriate.  The text solution merely indicates that $$(\lnot p \land q) \land r \equiv \lnot p \land q \land r$$ because *all the connectives are conjunctives* ($\land$).  That is, with all connectives conjunction, or with all connectives disjunction, we have associativity.  (Your use of parentheses does not make *your* answer wrong.  It is just as correct as the solution manual's answer.

So, e.g., $$(\lnot p \land q) \land r \equiv \lnot p \land (q \land r) = \lnot p \land q \land r$$

---

Your second answer is correct, as well, and here, your correct use of parentheses is crucial, because implication is not associative, and so the use of the comma, which you transcribed correctly, is crucial.

---

Don't ever hesitate to use the parentheses you use in the first example, or the second. Better to use parentheses, even if you don't need them, than to omit them, when they are crucial.